Minimum value mismatch
Say we want to minimize the sum $S = 9 + k^{2}$ which is clearly $9$.
But We know $(k-3)^{2} \geq 0$ Which gives $k^{2} + 9 \geq 6k$, so Minimum value of $S$ is $6k$ and clearly the equality holds when $k - 3 = 0$ which gives the minimum value of $S$ as $18$.
I'm really confused and unable to find the mistake in my reasoning.
I asked some of my friends for help, but none were able to help.
Any hint or help is appreciated.

Isn't it obvious your estimate of $S$ doesn't really bound it? Minimising $(k-3)^2$ isn't the same as minimising $S$, that's it.

When $x = 3$, you find that the parabola $y = x^2 + 9$ touches the slanted line $y = 6x$. But, there's nothing to say that this point produces a minimum. Indeed, this line is tangent to the parabola, and the fact that it's not horizontal suggests that $x = 3$ is definitely not the minimising $x$.

Read my related answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4924159/654465 I hope it will be clear.

First of all, your second approach is flawed.
If $S=9+k^2\ge6k$ then it doesn't mean that the minimum value of the function is $6k$. This is just a lower bound.
Also, how are you saying that the maximum of $S$ will occur when $9+k^2=6k?$
Think about this.
